# Vite build uses require? Receive error require is not defined

Tags: vue.js, requirejs, vite, electron-builder

I have an app that uses Vite (runs on electron, using electron builder and the plugin for vite) and I had a single page app and the build/app/etc were working great.  But, I needed to add a new page to the app and I'm running into the following problem.

But I now get a "require is not defined" error when I run the app.

I followed the docs for a multi-page app build from here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app

My vite.config.js looks like the following:

```
import { rmSync } from 'fs'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import electron from 'vite-electron-plugin'
import { customStart } from 'vite-electron-plugin/plugin'
import renderer from 'vite-plugin-electron-renderer'
import pkg from './package.json'
import {resolve} from 'path'

rmSync('dist-electron', { recursive: true, force: true })

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    electron({
      include: ['electron'],
      transformOptions: {
        sourcemap: !!process.env.VSCODE_DEBUG,
      },
      // Will start Electron via VSCode Debug
      plugins: process.env.VSCODE_DEBUG
        ? [customStart(debounce(() => console.log(/* For `.vscode/.debug.script.mjs` */'[startup] Electron App')))]
        : undefined,
    }),
    // Use Node.js API in the Renderer-process
    renderer({
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }),
  ],
  server: process.env.VSCODE_DEBUG ? (() => {
    const url = new URL(pkg.debug.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    return {
      host: url.hostname,
      port: +url.port,
    }
  })() : undefined,
  clearScreen: false,
  build: {
    assetsDir: '', // #287
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        project: resolve(__dirname, 'project.html')
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I have two HTML pages now (index.html and project.html).  The vite build now splits the JS bundles into two JS files for each page.  Here is the output for the project.html:

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Project</title>
    <link href="./assets/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./assets/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./assets/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./project.813f02b1.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./index.5b8fa581.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.acc344b1.css">
  </head>
```

But, vite then adds a "require('/index.5b8fa581.js')" within the "project.js" file.  Of course, this generates a "require is not defined" error when I run the app.

After searching and reading quite a bit, I tried to add the rollup plugin for CommonJS thinking that might help...  Doesn't help as I'm not using any "require" statements in any my Vue app code.  But, I thought possibly it might assist the vite build to convert the "require" statement they include in the build output to something the browser can load.

How do I fix this?  I find it strange (I must be missing some configuration for vite somehow) that the vite / rollup build would emit a 'require' statement in the build output.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . The config clearly differs from what's suggested in docs. Electron plugin is a clear difference and I'd expect to primarily affect the output

Comment: Thanks removed images.